# hide ul on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hide

I guess my problem needs more explanation. I am trying to get my drop down menu to function correctly on the ipad. I have top level menu items and sub menu items. When I tap the top level, the sub menu drops down, which is correct. Then when I tap one off the sub menu items, my html page loads inside my index.html (#!affordable-holidays.html). The problem is that the sub level drop down does not disappear when the html loads dynamically. So once I have tapped a parent item, the sub menu is there forever.

I thought that having some javascript at the top of the dynamically loaded html to hide the ul would work.

I am not sure of the correct terminology of how the page loads as this was a purchased template. For an example, mysite.com would be the index, and then when I go to another page it is mysite.com#!second-page.html

How would I hide a ul in a menu when the page loads?
This is my html

```
<li><a href="#">Tester</a>
    <ul class="menu-hide">
       <li ><a href="#!pay-as-you-go.html"><span class="title">PAY AS YOU GO</span></a></li>
       <li ><a href="#!affordable-holidays.html"><span class="title">AFFORDABLE HOLIDAYS ALWAYS</span></a></li>
       <li ><a href="#!how-points-work.html"><span class="title">HOW POINTS WORK</span></a></li>
       <li ><a href="#!more-than-a-room.html"><span class="title">MORE THAN A ROOM</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is the javascript I have found that is close to what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("div.menu-hide").hide()</script>
```

But I can't seem to target ul.menu-hide. I have tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("ul.menu-hide").hide()</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you hide it via your stylesheet and then reveal it on demand? Could save you a FOUC.

Comment: Did you tried after the dom loaded.i.e $(document).ready(function() {
}) and i agree with m90

Comment: @m90 - If it's going to be revealed via JS it is (often) better to hide via JS so that in browsers with JS disabled the page is still usable...

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function () {

   $("div.menu-hide").hide()
  })
</script>
```

you can also use the

```
 $(window).ready(function () {

       $("div.menu-hide").hide()
      })
```

but the difference is that  The document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet.

The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.

**Good Read**

[$(document).ready vs. $(window).load](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

Comment: Isn't that article contradicting your use of `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: You'd probably have flashing / flickering when you hide sth (that you want to be hidden from the start) just after all images have loaded. The ability to access the DOM should suffice for that?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing your document.ready call

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("ul.menu-hide").hide()});</script>
```

also ensure that the link to your jQuery library is declared **before** your other javascript

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: This is almost working. It does what I have asked, but now there is another problem. I have just edited my question which explains further. Your suggestion does hide the correct ul when the page starts to load, but is there a way to make it available again once the page has finished loading? As the ul is in a menu, it needs to be hidden at the start of the page load, and then made available again.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding an HTML element on page load via JavaScript will result in the element producing a flickering effect when it is displayed and then hidden.

I would hide the element with your css file, and then show via JavaScript.

css code:

```
.menu-hide{ display: none; }
```

jQuery show code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu-hide').show();
});
```

Comment: The down side of this approach however means any user with javascript turned off will never see this menu.

Comment: @SimonWest This is a very good point. You could incorporate a noscript tag which applies a `display: block` style in that case. However, I would not use javascript for a menu anyway and would use pure css.